# Getting 502 Gateway Error in Eureka + Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I am working in a microservice project where I am using Eureka as Service Registry and Spring Cloud Gateway as Api Gateway.

Consider following MS:

MyEurekaService [Service Registry]  => Context path: /MyClient/cloudDiscovery/

MyApiGateway [Spring Cloud Gateway] => Context Path : /MyClient/cloudGateway

MyOrderService [another ms register to Eureka]=> Context Path: /MyClient/MyOrder

in Api Gateway YML=>

```
  cloud:
   gateway:
     discovery:
         locator:
             enabled: true
             lowerCaseServiceId: true
     routes:
          - id: myorder-services
            uri: http://localhost:8085
            predicates:
               - Path=/MyClient/cloudGateway/MyClient/MyOrder/**
```

**Please note when I am accessing Eureka console at http://localhost:8761/MyClient/cloudDiscovery/
I can see both MyApiGateway  and MyOrderService  registered over there**

**Now MyGateway is running on port 8765.**
And I want to access a service /fetchOrder via Api Gateway, so, following URL I am trying:

```
http://localhost:8765/MyClient/cloudGateway/MyClient/MyOrder/fetchOrder
```

But it is giving 502 Gateway Error. Can anyone figure out what is the issue???